# SQL Join tables on different column types

Tags: sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys, left-join, entity-framework-core

I have two tables:

```
dbo.Dashboards
Id (int PK)  Title(nvarchar)  WidgetIds(nvarchar)
1            Test             [1,2]

dbo.Widgets
Id (int PK)  Details(nvarchar)
1            {'text': 'some data'}
2            {'text': 'test'}
```

Expected output:

```
Dashboard.Id     Dashboard.Title     Widget.Id     Widget.Details
1                Test                1             {'text': 'some data'}
1                Test                2             {'text': 'test'}
```

I would like to get dashboards with assigned widgets by using Entity Framework.
My first solution is to get `dbo.Dashboards` and then `dbo.Widgets`. After that I can merge it in a backend, but it is not the best practice.

Is there any option to get Dashboards with assigned Widget list?
Function `Include()` is not working because there isn't FK relationship between tables.

Comment: Also please add required output

Comment: Looks like your are storing some Json encoded data in your tables. I guess this is an existing database and you cannot change it - can you confirm that?  If yes, what does `WidgetIds` column contain for empty list (e.g. `null` or `[]`) and for single item list(e.g. `[1]`)?

Comment: This is an existing database, but I have an opportunity to change it if I have a serious reason. `WidgetIds` for empty list contains empty array`[]`, for single item it contains array with one element eg. `[1]`. In other words, this column contains JSON, we can easily open it using SQL function `OPENJSON()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have a many-to-many relationship between `Dashboards` and `Widgets`: Every `Dashboard` has zero or more `Widgets` and every `Widget` is used by zero or more `Dashboards`.

In a proper database you would have a separate [junction table](https://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/understanding-a-sql-junction-table/). Apparently you chose not to use this pattern, but create a string that contains a textual representation of the widgets that a 'Dashboard` has.

> If you plan to create a serious application I strongly advise you to
>   use the standard pattern in many-to-many relationships

If you don't, all your queries will be more difficult. Imagine the problems you'll experience if you want to delete a Widget. You'd have to check the textual representation of every Dashboard to check if the widget that you want to remove is used somewhere and change it.

If you want to configure your many-to-many relations ship according to the [Entity Framework Code-First Conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), you will have something like this:

```
class Dashboard
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Title {get; set;}

     // every Dashboard has zero or more Widgets
     public virtual ICollection<Widget> Widgets {get; set;}

     ... // other properties
}

class Widget
{
     public int Id {get; set;}

     // every Widget is used in zero or more Dashboards
     public virtual ICollection<Dashboard> Dashboards{get; set;}

     ... // other widget properties
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Dashboard> Dashboards {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Widget> Widgets {get; set;}
}
```

Because you stuck to the conventions, this is all that entity framework needs to know to understand that you want to configure a many-to-many relationship between Dashboards and Widgets. Entity Framework will create the junction table for you. It will automatically update this table whenever you add a Widget to a Dashboard. It will also create the proper joins whenever you want to fetch Dashboards with their Widgets, or Widgets with the Dasheboards that use them.

Your query will be fairly simple:

```
var DashBoardsWithTheirWidgets = myDbcontext.Dashboards

    // I only want to see the super dashboards
    .Where(dashboard => dashboard.Type = DashboardType.Super)

    .Select(dashboard => new
    {
        // Select only the properties you plan to use:
        Id = dashboard.Id,
        Title = dashboard.Title,

        // select only the Widgets you plan to use:
        Widgets = dashboard.Widgets
            .Where(widget => widget.Price > 100.00)
            .Select(widget => new
            {
                 // again select only the properties you plan to use
                 Name = widget.Name,
                 Price = widget.Price,
            })
            .ToList();
    });
```

See how easy it is if you stick to the conventions?

If you really want your obscure method of using foreign keys, you need a function to remove the square brackets and the commas from the widgetIds, split the string into sub-strings, Parse them to numbers, and do a join.

But before you plan to continue on this path, experiment on how to add a Widget and a Dashboard. How to add a Widget to a Dashboard, how to remove a Widget. I think the time needed to reform your database into proper format is much less than the time you'll need to implement those functions

Comment: As usual you are mixing EF6 with EF **Core**. EF **Core** does not support many-to-many relationships this way. So while in general you are right, it's worth reading EF **Core** concepts before trying to answer EF **Core** related questions.

Comment: Maybe, but one of the tags clearly said entity-framework. Seeing the way his foreign keys were designed, I thought that the asker wasn't really familiar with databases and was still in the phase of deciding how to do it, where one of the possibilities would be entity framework. Any other reason to use both tags, other than to get answers using both methods?

Comment: EF Core supersedes EF tag (after all, it contains Entity Framework in the name). What I meant is when suggesting concrete design or sample, to take EF Core into account (including the links). Some things like one-to-one, alternate keys are better supported in EFC, some like many-to-many with implicit junction table are not yet supported etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1:

You need to restructure the dbo.dashboards table. Change the column layout of dbo.dashboards to 
**Auto_Generated_ID, Unique_Identifier(PK), Title, WidgetIds**

I know the above column restructuring is done in a bad way. But still this will work in your case.

After redesigning it you can use join between dbo.dashboards and dbo.widgets to retrieve it in an efficient way.

> Solution 2:

The below-normalized tables will work in your case

**dbo.dashboard**

id, title (columns)

**dbo.dashboard_widget**

id, dashboard_id, widget_id (columns)

**dbo.widgets**

id, details (columns)

**Query:**

select d.id, d.title, dw.widget_ids, w. details from dbo.dashboard d INNER JOIN dbo.dashboard_widget dw ON d.id = dw.dashboard_id INNER JOIN dbo.widgets w ON dw.widget_id = w.id where d.id = << id number >>